# SAML integration with Nagios

Tags: saml, nagios

I am trying to integrate Nagios with SimpleSAMLPHP for SingleSignOn company wide.
I have installed simplesaml and Nagios on apache.

Looking out for configuration settings wherein I can specify SAML settings for Nagios.

Has anyone worked on it?

Comment: Hi @Naina were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think it's possible to do this without setting the Apache REMOTE_USER variable.** The Nagios server is rendered by php and cgi scripts. The php scripts have a user variable attached to the Apache server's REMOTE_USER, and this can be removed to substitute for any other php variable. BUT, most of the functionality and restrictions are being processed in the cgi scripts.

Based on [this issue on the Nagios Core GitHub repo](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/issues/63), it doesn't look like they are planning on offering any other methods of passing information to the cgi scripts. Nagios X doesn't appear to offer any options either [based on this forum post](https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=37875)

For authentication in Nagios Core these may be the best options:

1. Continue using Htaccess Authentication
2. Wrap the entire application within another to protect it (but you lose per-user privileges)
3. Manually change the Apache REMOTE_USER variable when someone logs in (maybe a security risk if at all possible)
4. Migrate to Icinga, which does offer more authentication options

At my place of employment, we will likely be using #3 or #4 based on what's possible and more secure.